# How do i lock the screen on click of conversation in inbox?

Tags: android, sms

I am new in android 
please help me on 
when i click  conversation in inbox first lock screen has to appear if the password is correct then message should open. how can i do that.

Answer (score 0):

When you click on a conversation, open a [Dialog](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomDialog).  Perform password validation.  If validation succeeds, [close the dialog](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#DismissingADialog) and open the message.
Instead of dialog, you can start another activity that performs password validation.  Use [startActivityForResult()](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html#StartingAnActivityForResult).

Comment: Thanks yuri for your answer But i need to Bind my activity class with default messaging Acticity. When i click on default messaging icon it will open inbox and then when i click on conversation then it will start my lock activity..      Tell me can i do this much ???